# Cause OutOfMemoryError intentionally without additional programs

Tags: java, testing, out-of-memory

### Background

I am building two Java applications:

1. A Web application runs on a Tomcat
2. A batch application runs on RHEL

I want to test the command line options of the `java` command were set properly. For example, I want to test a heap dump file (`.hprof`) generated when an OutOfMemoryError is caused in those Java applications.

### Problem

I want to run those tests on a test server. According to a rule of our project, I can't add additional programs unrelated to the application business logic.

### Question

Is there any way to cause OutOfMemoryError intentionally without additional programs?

Note:

- I can't change the parameters of the `-Xmx` and `-Xms` options only for this test. The reasons are:

  1. Because it's not preferable to change what I'm testing only for the test (it is a test of the set of java command line options for this application rather than a test of a single command line option itself). If I change what I'm testing only for the test, I have to have another demonstration that the change doesn't affect the result of the test (i.e. `.hprof` is written properly and contains what I want to analyze the cause of `OutOfMemoryError` in the application).
  2. It is difficult to predict the appropriate size of `-Xmx` and `-Xms` for every application. When you set `-Xmx64m`, a simple Java batch application with no frameworks will finish with no `OutOfMemoryError`. On the other hand, a Java batch application with Spring Boot and Spring Batch will not be able to launch with `-Xmx64m` and confirm the `.hprof` contains what I want for error analyses.
- In the web application, it is difficult to read a large test dataset and store them in memory (there are no functional requirements that read large datasets).
- In the batch application, the application is designed to
  be able to handle large datasets with a certain amount of memory, so memory consumption is not affected by the size of the test dataset.

Comment: Why can't you change the memory parameters for a test?  Seems like an unreasonable constraint.

Comment: Thank you for your question. The reason (1) it's not preferable to change what I'm testing only for the test (it is a test of the set of java command line options for this application rather than a test of a single command line option itself). If I change what I'm testing only for the test, I have to have another demonstration that the change doesn't affect the result of the test (i.e. `.hprof` is written properly and contains what I want to analyze the cause of `OutOfMemoryError` in the application).

Comment: The reason (2) it is difficult to predict the appropriate size of `-Xmx` and `-Xms` for every applications. When you set `-Xmx64m`, a simple Java batch application with no frameworks will finish with no `OutOfMemoryError`. On the other hand, a Java batch application with Spring Boot and Spring Batch will not be able to launch with `-Xmx64m` and confirm the `.hprof` contains what I whant for error analyses. I have also added the answers to your question in the note of the question.

Answer (score 1):

throw(new OutOfMemoryError("bam"));

Comment: Of course, you can cause `OutOfMemoryError` this way, but you have to add this code to the runtime environment. Is there any way to insert this code without changing the deployed application in runtime (for example, with some JMX functions)?